# rewrite to redirect to /app/web/path1/path2[etc] to /app/web/index.php/path1/path2[etc]

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to create a rewrite rule that allows:

/app/web/morepath/morepath2 to rewrite as /app/web/index.php/morepath/morepath2 (more path items if provided).

I don't want the URL in the browser to reflect the changed path (with index.php inserted after /app/web).

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the document root, try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+app/web/index\.php/?([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php
RewriteRule ^app/web/(.*) /app/web/index.php/$1 [L]
```